# Using node.js JUST to read the file path

Tags: node.js, filesystems

Is it possible to just read the file name/path from a user trying to upload content to the server?

For example, when a user selects some files to be uploaded before they are actually uploaded to the server I would like to read the file information.

[fs.readdir](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_callback) can be used to read the contents of the directory but how about user selected files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. Browsers would only allow the filename to be sent when you upload the file. Doing so would mean exposing your directory structure to the server. (very bad idea)

It is a security standard and a good practice, not to give up the full location of file that you are sending to the server. There should separate paths for handling the file on server and on the client side.